# launch 3rd party application from native iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I have to do an application that should be launched from the iPhone native applications like calendar, contacts and mail box etc... is it possible to launch 3rd party application from the native app, whether apple allows the developer to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible and quite east in fact. You have to create a custom URL that launch your app.

E.g ***myApp://?param=value*** look at [this excellent tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Then in the email you click on the URL and your app is launched... This solutino work only in apps that recognize  URL

Comment: True, but the question is about launching other apps from within your own app.

Comment: "launch 3rd party application from native iPhone apps" "that application should be launch from the iPhone native applications". You should consider rewriting your question.. To answer : you can launch Mail, SMS, Safari, use contacts, use Photo library and launch phone calls. You can't use or launch Calendar app.